# Word 2019 select text Backcolor Property

Tags: vba, ms-word, format

I am looking for the code to modify the Selected text editor backcolor with Visual Basic code.

I recorded a macro and found the below code to modify colors in the active document:

```
ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = wdThemeColorAccent2
ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = -0.25
ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Solid
```

I am searching for the code to modify the active selected text backcolor/not the highlight color.

for example:

```
ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.BackColor.SelectedTextThemeColor = wdThemeColorAccent2
```

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro while you modify the active selected text backcolor/not the highlight color? Most likely the `Selection` object needs to get involved somehow.

Comment: Im' guessing you want `.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor` or something related (the above does an entire row or cell).

Answer (score 0):

The background color of selected text in Office 2019 is hard coded in the programs and is not modifiable with VBA.

Comment: Is there a way to go through command prompt to edit the source code ?Hard coding is the software development practice of embedding data directly into the source code of a program or other executable object, as opposed to obtaining the data from external sources or generating it at run-time. Hard-coded data typically can only be modified by editing the source code and recompiling the executable, although it can be changed in memory or on disk using a debugger or hex editor.

Comment: Can a small sub program written in C , else another language be entered into a developer module to modify the code ? Are there any textbooks you know of which give source code for the ActiveDocuments for Word 2019  system settings?

Comment: Your approach might work with a program built in an interpreted language, but not in a compiled one. When a program is compiled, the source code is not included. That remains at Microsoft offices.